# cannot read property 'closest' of undefined in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm currently set the data of the kendo grid A to kendo grid B. but i have a problem with `cannot read property 'closest' of undefined in kendo grid`

please help me..

this is the code of onclick by button of kendo B

```js
 $("#add-Resources").click(function () {
            var gridModal = $("#resourcesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var selectedItemModal = gridModal.dataItem(gridModal.select());

            var grid = $("#tblDelivery").data("kendoGrid");
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem(grid.current().closest("tr"));
            dataItem.set("Resource", selectedItemModal.Name);
            //alert(selectedItemModal.Name);
            $('#resources_modal').modal('toggle');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `current` takes parameter which represents the navigatable cell. Use `current(someJqueryElement)`, then you're able to call `closest`. i.e.

```
current(someJqueryElement).closest('tr');
```

[Here's](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/current) `telerik` documentation for `current` method.

You can also see [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/olAxo) `dojo` as sample code to use `current` method.

Comment: thanks bro, but i just pick set navigatable: true on my grid and it still working with current().closest('tr')

Comment: Yeah, you're right. `navigatable: true` is used in `dojo` sample.